$X^{6}+(T-22) X^{4}+T X^{3}+(T-22) X^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(T)$
I'm asked to prove that $f(X)=X^{6}+(T-22) X^{4}+T X^{3}+(T-22) X^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(T)$.
For this, I need first to prove that the polynomials $p(X) = X^{6}-22 X^{4}-22 X^{2}+1$ and $q(X) = X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb Q[X]$. Which I did by noticing that the roots in $\mathbb C$ of $q$ are $0, j, \overline{j}$ where $j = e^{\frac{2 i \pi}{3}}$ and that none is a root of $p$.
Obviously, $p$ is deduced from $f$ by letting $T=0$. However, I don't know how to deduce the irreducibility of $f$ from there. Any idea?

By Gauss's lemma and friends it suffices to prove irreducibility over $\Bbb{Q}[T]$. That is, we need to disprove the existence of a factorization $f(X,T)=g(X,T) h(X,T)$ with $g,h\in\Bbb{Q}[T,X]$. But $f$ has degree ove over $T$, so either $g$ or $h$ must be a polynomial of $X$ alone. Also $f(X,T)= T q(X)+ p(X)$, so that factor needs to be common to $q$ and $p$.

I expect there to exist a near duplicate target...

May be this old answer of yours? :-) I seem to have upvoted that post back in the day!

@JyrkiLahtonen Thanks to remind me what I did 6 years ago, and for your today comments!

Hint If $f(X)$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb Q[T]$, then the polynomial given by evaluating at $T = 22$,
$$f_{22}(X) := X^6 + 22 X^3 + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x] ,$$
is not irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

 Now, $f_{22}(X + 1)$ is Eisenstein at $3$, so $f_{22}(X)$ is irreducible, hence $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q[T]$.

